# Best way to handle an npm packages dependencies?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

I am trying to breakout a couple of Vue.js components from a primary application into an npm package stored on a repository. This package can then be imported and used across two separate sites. I am using Webpack to bundle everything but have had a few queries about the layout that should be used.

Seeing that things like Vue.js and Vuex will installed as dependencies on the main application, I know that the package will have access to these once installed on the two main applications.

My primary confusion is how do I deal with dependencies that belong to the package only, do I bundle this as part of the webpack and will running `npm install` on the applications automatically install the 'dependencies dependencies' if you will? Is there a general standard for these things?

Comment: best way to find out is to try it.  You need this : https://vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html and yes it will install what ever is in module package.json dep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest thing to do is list them in your `dependencies` section in `package.json`. The package manager tool you're using (usually either `npm` or 'yarn`) will take responsibility for deduping the dependences, so if your parent app and your subproject both have the same dependencies, you'll only end up with one copy in the final bundle.

I would strongly suggest that you be looser on version numbers in the component projects then you are in the parent project. So in the parent maybe you say the dependency is `"vue": "1.2.3"` and in the component project it's `"vue": "^1.1.0"` or something along those lines. This way the parent can control the specific versions and your component picks up the actual version from the parent.

Comment: So my understanding is just keep the package.json/lock files within my custom package and leave out my package node_modules dir entirely when bundling and committing and use my deployment to install these manually from the parent application ```npm install```?

Comment: Yep. That's generally a good plan for components or libraries in general - specify the dependencies and let the tools actually pull them. Unless you have a very specific version requirement it makes maintenance a lot easier.